# Fragment detach() and attach() doesn't update view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer in my Application and want to change the `TextView` in the Menu from Login (when no user is logged in) to My Account (when a user logs in). I use `attach()` and `detach()` methods to reload the fragment. However, the view doesn't seem to get updated. Using logs, I have verified that the piece of code executes correctly.

Here is the `onClick` action that happens when I click logout, which seems to successfully logout my user. `SharedPrefs` is a class used to manage `SharedPreferences`. The `deletePrefs()` method works good, because if I press logout and restart the application, the user is successfully logged out.

```
                case 2:
                SharedPrefs.deletePrefs(getContext());
                closeDrawer();

                NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment = MainActivity.getNavigationDrawerFragment();
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUserData("", "", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avatar));

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit();
                Log.d("Fragment", "detach, attach");
                break;
```

Here is the method that builds the Menu. It is called in the `onCreateView()` method of my Fragment.

```
  public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
        items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_home)));
        if (!SharedPrefs.isLogin(getContext()))
            items.add(new NavigationItem("Login", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_login)));
        else
            items.add(new NavigationItem("My Account", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_my_account)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Logout", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_logout)));
        return items;
    }
```

When detaching and attaching, isn't `onCreateView()` executed again? Thus the Menu should get rebuilt and the `TextView` should change, right?

EDIT: So using logs, I see that the `onCreateView()` method is not called again when detaching and reattaching. Is this normal? Or am I detaching and reattaching the wrong way?

Comment: Why would onCreateView be executed again? The fragment view has already been created.

Comment: @cyroxis Because detaching and attaching the fragment recreates the View, thus onCreateView is called again. Isn't that correct?

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51327440/4514796

Comment: onCreateView is called but the view isn't updated. It has the previous view. can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem while using fragment update. I fixed it like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(this).attach(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```